# CSS: background-color on section tag doesn't cover full width?

Tags: html, css

Foremost there are a lot of posts relating to `background-color`. I have read several and have tried various solutions posted there from setting `background-size` to making overflow hidden. Nothing seems to work....
How can I get `background-color` to cover the whole section?

I have a very simple M.W.E. below:

## html

```
<body>
<section>
  TEST!
</section>
</body>
```

## css

```
body {
  background-color: coral;
}

section {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/7Ldzmson/1/)

Comment: everything is ok.what u want to do in section?

Comment: removing that little padding's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `margin:auto` on body tag

snippet below

```css
body {
  background-color: coral;
  margin:auto;
}

section {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<body>
<section>
  TEST!
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: That works! Thanks. But why does changing the body affect the section? Especially since the background-color of the body already spans the whole thing?

Comment: In terms resizing the no. since width 100% is applied. If you change certain property like font on the body the children elements may inherit. But you can override such property of the parent by styling the children

Comment: the section is in the body hence changing certain properties from the body may or may not affect its children elements... It is an inheritance sort of thing with css

Comment: In this case the body has no margin (outer whitespace), the child, section will now occupy this margin which is now remove (since you set a width of 100%)

Comment: ah.... I now about inheritance, I just didn't figure that margins would be the cause since the body's background was fine.... I just posted another question, could you maybe take a look at that real quick?

Comment: my apologies friend..I gotta go pick up my family....there are alot of gurus on this site that will tackle the new question..I am out

Answer (score 1):

There is a default margin on the `body` element, so you should always add this rule:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Here it is applied to your example: https://jsfiddle.net/93669xwh/

Answer (score 0):

The full width of the page?

You can reset or eradicate with:

```
*, html, body { 
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

[**Updated jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7Ldzmson/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading about "reseting css", zeroing margin and padding of body, html, p and etc. It can solve your problem.
[reset-css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)